# Program won't read the inputted name to edit other info

Tags: c++

When I input the info needed in `addstudent()`, it works. But when I try to edit the info, using the name I input to search for the info to edit, it doesn't work.

Here is the sample:

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

struct studmem{
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char course[50];
    int yrlvl;
    char spcl[50];
}s[10];


void addstudent(studmem s[],int lngth, int &val){
        for (int i = 0; i < lngth; i += 1) {
        int CheckCharacter = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        int CheckCharacters = 0;

    do{
    int chkchr=1;
    cout<<"Enter name: ";
    cin.getline(s[val].name,50);
    
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s[val].name);i++){
    if(!(isalpha(s[val].name[i])||isspace(s[val].name[i]))){
        cout<<"Invalit input! Please try again!\n";
        chkchr=0;
        break;
            }
    }
     if(chkchr==1){
            break;
    }
}while(1);
    
        
    
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
     cin >> s[val].age;
    cin.ignore();
        while (s[val].age >= 35 || s[val].age <= 17) {
    cout << "Invalid age. Please enter your age again: ";
    cin >> s[val].age;
    }
        
        while (CheckCharacter == 0) {
            cout << "Enter Course: ";
            cin.getline(s[val].course, 30);
            if (strcmp(s[val].course, "BSIT") == 0)
            {
                CheckCharacter++;
            }
            else if (strcmp(s[val].course, "BSCS") == 0) {
                CheckCharacter++;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid Input! Please try again!" << endl;
            }
        }
    
    
    do{
            CheckCharacter = 0;
            cout << "Enter Year Level: ";
            cin >> s[val].yrlvl;
            if (s[val].yrlvl >= 1 && s[val].yrlvl <= 4){
                CheckCharacter++;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Enter Year Level Again!\n";
            }
    }while (CheckCharacter == 0);
    
            
            CheckCharacter = 0;
        cin.ignore();
        while (CheckCharacter == 0) {
            cout << "Enter Specialization: ";
            cin.getline(s[val].spcl, 50);
            if (strcmp(s[val].course, "BSIT") == 0)
            {
                if (strcmp(s[val].spcl, "AGD") == 0)
                    CheckCharacter++;
                else if (strcmp(s[val].spcl, "DA") == 0)
                    CheckCharacter++;
                else if (strcmp(s[val].spcl, "WMA") == 0)
                    CheckCharacter++;
                else if (strcmp(s[val].spcl, "SMBA") == 0)
                    CheckCharacter++;
                else
                {
                    cout << "Invalid Input. Please Enter Specialization Again";
            
                }
            }
            
            
            else if (strcmp(s[val].course, "BSCS") == 0) {
                if (strcmp(s[val].spcl, "SE") == 0)
                    CheckCharacter++;
                else if (strcmp(s[val].spcl, "DS") == 0)
                    CheckCharacter++;
                else
                {
                    cout << "Invalid Input. Please Enter Specialization Again";
            
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "Invalid Input. Please Enter Specialization Again(For BSIT: WMA, DA, AGD, SMBA For BSCS: DS, SE)";
                
            }
        }
        val += 1;
    }
}



void edstudent(studmem s[]){
    int CheckCharacter=0;

    do{
        char studname[50];
        cout<<"Search Name of Student: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(studname,50);
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(s[i].name);i++){
            if((strcmp(studname,s[i].name))==0){
                CheckCharacter++;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Student not found, please try again!\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(CheckCharacter=0);
}



int main(){
    bool Code = 1;
    int rec=0;
    int list = 0;
    int value = 0;
    
    
    do {
        int ch;

        cout << "Student Record" << endl;
        cout << "1) Add" << endl;
        cout << "2) View" << endl;
        cout << "3) Edit" << endl;
        cout << "4) Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Maximum of 10 Students" << endl;
        cout << "No. of Students: " << rec << endl;
        cout << "\nChoice: ";
        cin >> ch;
        cin.ignore();

        switch (ch) {

        case 1: {

            rec += 1;
            addstudent(s, 1, value);
                break;

            }

        case 2:{
        
        for(int i=0;i<rec;i++){
            cout<<"Student #"<<i+1;
            cout<<"\nName: "<<s[i].name<<endl;
            cout<<"Age: "<<s[i].age<<endl;
            cout<<"Course: "<<s[i].course<<endl;
            cout<<"Year Level: "<<s[i].yrlvl<<endl;
            cout<<"Specialization: "<<s[i].spcl<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
        }
            break;
        }
        
        case 3:{
            edstudent(s);
            
            break;
        }


        default:
            cout<<"Invalid Input! Please try again!\n";
            main();
        }

        } while (1);
    }
```

I tried changing `(int i=0;i<strlen(s[i].name);i++)` because they say it's the problem, but it just doesn't work.

The main problem is here, I think:

```
void edstudent(studmem s[]){
    int CheckCharacter=0;

    do{
        char studname[50];
        cout<<"Search Name of Student: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(studname,50);
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(s[i].name);i++){
            if((strcmp(studname,s[i].name))==0){
                CheckCharacter++;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Student not found, please try again!\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(CheckCharacter=0);
}
```

Hoping you can help me, since I'm new to C++.

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" means? Please edit your post to include the program output as text instead of a picture, and add some info about what exactly is going wrong. Also consider using a debugger to go step by step through your program to see where it deviates from what you expect.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your code overall, I don't even know where to start. But, to answer your specific question - yes, `edstudent()` is **seriously** flawed. It is not reading in the searched name correctly (hint: `cin.ignore()` doesn't belong in this function at all). It is not iterating through the array of students correctly. It is not comparing the names correctly. And, it is breaking the loop at the wrong time. In short, *everything* about this function is wrong.